# Having two different order, and limit statements in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a select statement, where I need to first order it by relevance, get the top ten relevance, order it by rand(), and then limit it by 1, but I don't think it's possible to do that with 2 different order, and limit statements. So, my question is, is there a workaround this problem? Thanks.

```
SELECT id, input, response, 
MATCH (
input
)
AGAINST (
 'cat frogs trees'
IN NATURAL LANGUAGE
MODE
) AS relevance
FROM allData
HAVING relevance >0
ORDER BY relevance DESC
LIMIT 10
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: i suggest leave the random pick to php, do the rest in the query

Comment: no. you can't have multiple `order by` clauses in a single query, you can have multiple TERMS in a SINGLE `order by`, hwoever. but since your ordering/limits are contradictory, you can't do that. you'll have to use subqueries and apply the limits/ordering as appropriate in each individual query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT id, input, response, 
             MATCH (input) AGAINST ('cat frogs trees' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS relevance
      FROM allData
      HAVING relevance > 0
      ORDER BY relevance DESC
      LIMIT 10
     ) t
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I just tried it. It works. But there's a tiny problem. It only selects whatever is the first one in SELECT. So in the example above, it only gets the id, and not the input, nor the response. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: @jessica . . . This query would return all those values.  If you are only getting one column, that must be at the application layer.